# Wildfly 9.1 smtp mail substem - Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

Tags: smtp, localhost, jakarta-mail, wildfly, wildfly-9

I'm working with wildfly as for a while and I cant get its mail subsystem working. I have seen many tutorials how to set it up whether through web console, CLI or directly in standalone.xml so I'm pretty sure that my config is right:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
        <mail-session debug="true" name="Gmail" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Gmail" from="MAILFROM">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp" ssl="true" username="MAILFROM" password="PASSWORD"/>
        </mail-session>
</subsystem>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

And then in my Java file:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/mail/Gmail")
private javax.mail.Session gmailSession;

public void sendEmail(String to,String subject,String msg){
 Message message = new MimeMessage(gmailSession);
 message.setFrom(newInternetAddress("MAILFROM"));
 message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
 InternetAddress.parse(to));
 message.setSubject(subject);
 message.setContent(msg,"text/html");
 Transport.send(message);}
```

And I get:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2054)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.liferoles.controller.UserManager.sendEmail(UserManager.java:487)
at com.liferoles.controller.UserManager.sendResetLink(UserManager.java:520)
at com.liferoles.rest.RestAuth.sendResetLink(RestAuth.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:329)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2020)
... 52 more
```

The weird thing is that **it works with same properties when using javax.mail API directly like this:**

```
public void sendEmail(String to,String subject,String msg){
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        String user = "MAILFROM";
        String passwd = "PASSWORD";
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        javax.mail.Session gmailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, passwd);
                    }
                  });
        Message message = new MimeMessage(gmailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("MAILFROM"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(msg,"text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
```

I'm trying to solve this issue for two reasons:

1. I want to have my credentials in standalone.xml not in my java class.
2. And mainly because I hate when something is weird and i cant get it working!

The second thing i do not understand clearly is why am I getting this exception:

```
    15:25:28,587 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorExc
eption: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid cert
ification path to requested target
15:25:28,587 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at com.liferoles.controller.UserManager.sendEmail(UserManager.java:484)
15:25:28,587 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at com.liferoles.controller.UserManager.sendResetLink(UserManager.java:5
14)
15:25:28,587 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   ... 44 more
15:25:28,588 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;

15:25:28,588 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   nested exception is:
15:25:28,588 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorExc
eption: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid cert
ification path to requested target
15:25:28,588 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2000)
15:25:28,588 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:70
9)
15:25:28,588 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
15:25:28,589 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
15:25:28,589 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
15:25:28,589 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
15:25:28,589 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
15:25:28,589 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   at com.liferoles.controller.UserManager.sendEmail(UserManager.java:481)
15:25:28,590 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)   ... 45 more
15:25:28,590 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.Val
idatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find v
alid certification path to requested target
```

when trying to send email by the second method I mentioned. This error only occurs in case that I am running starting my wildfly server from console with standalone.bat command.. If I am runing it through eclipse "run on server" it works. Confused for a second time. I tried to solve this second problem by adding my selfsigned certificate to jdks cacerts but it didn't help.

Comment: you are using different port in your "working" java code than one in xml configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of class is your Java code with @Resource in?  Most likely the resource is not being injected because your code is not in a managed bean/class of some sort.  Check whether gmailSession is non-null to make sure the injection is working.

The cert path error is definitely a problem with certificates in your trust store.  Normally the Gmail certificate should validate with the default trust store.  Perhaps you have an anti-virus product that's intercepting the request?  Did you check the [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert)?

Comment: Null test positive, you were right! G2g now, will try to solve it tomorrow and leave a message. Thanx for now :)

Comment: OK, both problems solved. In first case you were right so I changed resource injection to: gmailSession = InitialContext.doLookup("java:jboss/mail/Gmail"); You were right with the second problem also, initially I used the keytool bad way, your link helped me to solve it.
Thank you a lot!